# iOS: Textfield delegate, how to end edit automatically before processing a row move in a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

In my edit stage of my table view you can edit `UITextField`s in all cells and move the cells around as well. There is one little problem if you change the text of a certain textfield and immediately move that textfield or better that cell containing that textfield to another indexPath, because the text isn't saved yet. And then everything is messed up.

To solve this I basically want to automatically call `textFieldDidEndEditing` before starting the row move. That should work right? But how can I correctly end the editing of a textfield programmatically? By resigning first responder? And how would I do that?

```
My two relevant functions:
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    //Did End editing is always called first after ending the editing either by enter or by clicking the done button. So this method saves the newly entered text
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
    }

    self.activeField = nil;

    [self stopSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContextWithDelay:0.3f];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{
    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.

    //reordering has been defined in the CoreDataViewController so the
    //FetchedResultsController doesn't mess up the reordering since he would update
    //the fetched results permanently while reordering
    self.reordering = YES;

    //Makes only a mutable copy of the array, but NOT the objects (references) within
    NSMutableArray *fetchedResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving
    NSManagedObject *resultToMove = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [fetchedResults removeObject:resultToMove];
    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [fetchedResults insertObject:resultToMove atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 1;
    for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
    {
        fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
    }

    // Save
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // re-do the fetch so that the underlying cache of objects will be sorted
    // correctly
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    self.reordering = NO;
}
```

EDIT: My new code, still not working:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{

    if(self.activeField){
        [self saveTextFieldEntry:self.activeField];
    }
    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.

    //reordering has been defined in the CoreDataViewController so the
    //FetchedResultsController doesn't mess up the reordering since he would update
    //the fetched results permanently while reordering
    self.reordering = YES;

    //Makes only a mutable copy of the array, but NOT the objects (references) within
    NSMutableArray *fetchedResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving
    NSManagedObject *resultToMove = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [fetchedResults removeObject:resultToMove];
    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [fetchedResults insertObject:resultToMove atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 1;
    for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
    {
        fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
    }

    // Save
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // re-do the fetch so that the underlying cache of objects will be sorted
    // correctly
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    self.reordering = NO;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = textField;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
//    self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    //Did End editing is always called first after ending the editing either by enter or by clicking the done button. So this method saves the newly entered text
//    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
//    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//
//    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
//        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
//    }
//    
//    self.activeField = nil;

    [self saveTextFieldEntry:textField];

//    [self stopSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContextWithDelay:0.3f];
}

- (void)saveTextFieldEntry:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
    }

    self.activeField = nil;

    [self stopSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContextWithDelay:0.3f];
}
```

How can I be sure this save process is finished before the row move? Maybe that's the reason its not working because its slower than the move?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an instance variable, like :

```
UITextField * selectedTextField;
```

and change it in :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    selectedTextField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    selectedTextField = nil;
}
```

And wherever you make an action that requires to resign the active textfield, add :

```
if (selectedTextField && [selectedTextField isFirstResponder]) 
      [selectedTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I'm glad it did and Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Thanks! I was using slide to delete a row gesture and it had funky results when you were still editing a text field in a cell. Your suggestion fixed this for me!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly assign a unique tag value to every textField created in each cell of tableView and then use the method **textFieldDidBeginEditing:** Store the value of tag in a variable along with the text value and when user moves to next textField or fires **textFieldDidEndEditing:** method check whether the textField.tag value matched already stored value or not. If it matches then update whatever you want to with the tag value already stored in..

Comment: Oh man that's true..i've been working too long :-) Thx for the hint!

Comment: It happens when we move to the complex mode of thinking, sometimes small hints doesn't clicks out mind until someone buzz us

Comment: enjoy and have a blessed new year ahead

Comment: Hmm ok it still doesn't work as expected :/ I have now the code as in my edit but still after changing the text and immediately moving the row it isn't correctly saved..

Comment: You could do one more thing, just set userInteractionEnable to FALSE for rest of textfield until this textfield data is not saved. And add a toolbar on over the textField.

Answer (score 1):

Save the current textField in a property in your `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

and in your row move function make a invalidate call to the saved textField.